# Create Team for Organization with Terraform

Tags: github, terraform

I Want to create Team with Terraform, but i have more than one organization in my github account, can someone help me please? because i don't know how to configuration

Terraform Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must use terraform Provider

use this configuration : create Provider.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source = "integrations/github"
      version = "5.12.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "github" {
  token="{PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN FOR YOUR GITHUB ACCOUNT}"
  owner="{YOUR GITHUB ORGANIZATION USERNAME (Find it On Your Link Organization)}"
}
```

Disclaimer:if you want to upload it to your github please don't hardcode the token

Next you must get your Personal Acces Token with this :  [Click Me to Get Personal Acces Token for Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)   you can fill the Personal Access Token (PAT) to provider github token

You can create github team with this configuration : Create main.tf

```
resource "github_team" "{Name varibel for terraform}" {
  name        = {Name of Team}
  description = {Description For Github Team}
}
```

example :

```
resource "github_team" "team_alpha" {
      name        = "Alpha Team"
      description = "This Team Only For Alpha Organization"
    }
```